# Sonar - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30344

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm having this error while trying to analyze a project with Sonar Server:

> INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
>
> INFO: Total time: 50.063s Final Memory: 13M/164M
>
> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>
> ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
>
> ERROR: Caused by: Can not execute Findbugs
>
> ERROR: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30344
>
> ERROR: Caused by: 30344

We were using the default rules before and everything was working. We changed to other rules, and this error happened. It's weird 'cause they worked in other PC with the same set-up described below:

**Sonar-runner version: 2.4**

**Sonarqube version:4.5.1**

**Finbugs version: 2.4**

[image: First part of the Stack Trace]

Comment: if you changed the rules you probably have a error in a rule that is incomplete or something else that is causing this. This is off topic unless you are writing sonar specific code. Otherwise this is just a general configuration issue and you should submit a bug report to the sonar project.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest Findbugs SonarQube plugin, 3.1. That solved the issue for me. Please let us know.

1. Log in as admin
2. Under "settings" on the top menu
3. Click "Update center" in the left navigation
4. Now under "Plugin updates" in the content pane tabs
5. ...

But mostly I can't take my eyes off the righthand side of your screenshot. Some really excellent recursion going on. Thanks for that.